# fading in a class with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello so what i'm trying to accomplish is when user clicks on a button it will fade out the question and the buttons and fade in new question and button. The questions and buttons are images so what i tried to do is create a class and add the background-image: url("../img/"image.jpg"); but then it doesn't even make the image appear. So is there any way i can fade in new image of the question and button after a click of a button.

```js
//functions
function clickimageone(l) {
  alert("test");
  question1button1 = true;
}
```

```css
.questiontwo {
  background: url('../img/secondquestion.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="img/firstquestion.jpg" onclick="questionone()" class="question1" style="height: 350px; width: 600px; position: absolute; top: 130px; left: 620px">
<div class="image"><img src="img/500.png" onclick="clickimageone(this)" class="border1" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px;  max-width: 300px; position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 650px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/1000.png" onclick="clickimagetwo(this)" class="border2" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 780px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/1500.png" onclick="clickimagethree(this)" class="border3" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 910px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/2000.png" onclick="clickimagefour(this)" class="border4" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 1040px"></div>
<div class="questiontwo"></div>


<Script>
  $('.border1').click(function(e) {    
    $('.image, .border1, .border2, .border3, .border4, .question1, .contentanswer, .contentbackground')
      .fadeOut('slow', function() {
         $('.questiontwo').fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
</Script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code with simple `setTimeout`, and I also changed `background` to `background-image` property, because, as I know, transition doesn't work with `background` property, but with `background-image` it does.

```js
/*http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconsmind/outline/512/Chemical-icon.png*/

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.divWithImage').css("background-image", "url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconsmind/outline/512/Chemical-icon.png')")
  }, 1000)
})
```

```css
.divWithImage {
  background-image: url('https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  
  -webkit-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Change image</button>
<div class="divWithImage"></div>
```

You can also look at [jquery-bgswitcher](https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher) plugin.

Comment: This is perfect but how would i use class instead of id and add some second in the transition fade

Comment: @dropletgamb, I have updated the answer with `class` usage and simple `setTimeout`. I also changed `background` to `background-image`, because, as I know, `transition` doesn't work with `background` property, but with `background-image` it does.

Comment: @dropletgamb, is this solution OK for you?

Comment: Thank you this is what im looking for. now im gonna implement it into my code

Comment: My button is a image and it has a class and not a id and i tried to change the code in the jquery to .btn instead of #btn and it did not work

Comment: @dropletgamb, in your question the class is `questiontwo` if I understood correctly, so you need `$('.questiontwo').on('click', function() { ...`

Comment: So one of my last question is, im fading in multiple image and fading out multiple so would i add more of             $('.divWithImage').css("background-image", "url('img/intelbutton.png')") or add inside like this  $('.divWithImage, .divwithimage1').css("background-image", "url('img/intelbutton.png')")

Comment: @dropletgamb, if you want to fade-in-out background images **IN ONE** div, I can suggest you just to store stis div in variable `var divWithImage = $('.divWithImage')` and use `divWithImage` variable instead of getting this element from DOM every time. The result will be: `divWithImage.css("background-image", "url('img/intelbutton.png')")` for example

Comment: Okay actually, this is not gonna work out because i already have <img> set out not on class so im gonna need a alternative.

Comment: Is there a way you can edit my jquery to simply fade in new image that adds it's class or fade in new <div> and the <img>

Comment: how come this isnt working on my jquery           $('.questiontwo').fadeIn('slow');

Comment: @dropletgamb, SO is not a free code writing service. If you have some difficulties,  we will point you to the right direction and help with information, sure. So if your question is about `<img>` and fading now, you better create another one question on SO. Best regards =)